# Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more

Tags: support

I just notice in my account for programmers.stackexchange.com

The following message:

> Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more.[1]

Here my questions on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/30714/gibbok?tab=questions, they have all from 2 to 10 up votes, some where bookmarked.

Reading more on this site I have found this explanation for that warning message:

> ...heavily down-voted, zero-voted, or deleted posts. One or two bad posts will not cause you to be blocked from using the site...
>   https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans

I would like to ask more info on why this warning was sent and how could I improve my present questions.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 8 questions in total on the site.

6 of which are deleted now.

As you noted in your quote - deleted posts count towards the warning.

Please read the [what's on topic](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) section of the help center to avoid getting a ban.

Comment: Thanks for your message, could you please help me a little furthers... how do I see "deleted questions" in my control panel?

Comment: @GibboK: ask that 1 question is detached from your profile.. try to answer questions and mind more to the rules in the next times...

Comment: @GibboK - on your profile page, on the questions page there is a link at the bottom to see deleted recent questions (that will bring up questions that were asked in the last 60 days and were deleted), however all your deleted questions are older than that.